# How would you call this sum?

Tags: soft-question

One has:

- $\sum_n x^n$: sum of powers,
- $\sum_n \frac{1}{x^n}$: sum of reciprocal of powers,
- $\sum_p \frac{1}{x^p}$: ?

Note that $p\in\mathbb{P}$, where $\mathbb{P}$ denotes the set of prime numbers.

Comment: Sum of reciprocal-prime powers?

Comment: @Randall "Prime powers" usually refers to $p^n$, though, not $x^p$...

Comment: Sum of reciprocal pickle-powers.

Comment: @Randall Words are non-associative, and when you write words without brackets, you can't expect people to associate them the way you want them to, especially when you mess with words that usually come together :-)

Comment: Sum of reciprocal powers of $x$ with prime exponents.

Comment: @Alex Is there any way to shorten that?

Comment: I do not see a good way to shorten that.

Comment: easy to shorten just call it The Pickle 's Sum..

Comment: Sum of $x$ to the minus prime power.

Comment: Honest question:  why does it need a name?

Comment: @Randall Another way of saying would be "how would you describe this sum in as few terms as possible"?